# Этикетные формулы

Tags: этикет

какие ошибки допущены героями известных российских фильмов?

1. – Измерить температуру забортной воды не представляется возможным из-за отсутствия таковой! (м/ф «Приключения капитана Врунгеля»).
2. – Совсем не пью. Не имею физической возможности
   (к/ф «Кавказская пленница»).
3. – На это я пойтить не могу. Мне надо посоветоваться с
   шефом (к/ф «Бриллиантовая рука»).
4. – Нет уж, дудки, объясняйтесь сами! (к/ф «Ирония
   судьбы, или С легким паром»)

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этой викторины.

Comment: Пока вопрос не закрыли (а он того безусловно заслуживает) дам наводку. Здесь нет ошибок - за исключением, разве что, использования просторечного "пойтить". А этикетные формулы весьма субъективны и к сфере собственно русского языка не относятся